# how to build a regular expression using turbo pascal lex to pattern match accented letters?

Tags: regex

As mentioned above i'm trying to build a regex to take all the french letters including the accented ones. unfortunately the accented letters give me error all the time. is the pattern
`([a-zA-Z-âàçèé])+` is well formed ? any help will be appreciated.

Here is my Lex code sample:

```
%{
uses lexlib; 
%}
%%
"Exit:"
begin
halt;
end;
" " ;
([a-zA-Z-âàçèé])+
begin
writeln('word  : ' + yytext);
end;
.   begin
writeln('errorrrrrrrrrrrrrr  : ' + yytext);
end;
\n  ;
%%
begin
if yylex=0 then ;
end.
```

Comment: `-` is used to define a character range (example: `A-Z`)

Comment: ([a-zA-Z-âàçèé])+, the dash between Z and â should be ok if you intend it to be treated as a literal. What's the error? Try taking out the dash `[a-zA-Zâàçèé]`

Comment: Try to swap `-` to the end of the character class.

Comment: Could be it only reads 7-bit ascii, masks off high bit. Maybe its a problem. Take out accent chars one by one for a test.

Comment: ([â])+ even this regex is not working. it shows :  errorrrrrrrrrrrrrr  : â

Comment: Maybe try using [unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/#latin-1-supplement) range? `[a-zA-Z\u00E0\u00E2\u00E7-\u00E9]+`

Comment: as sln said i think that this version of turbo pascal lex does not handles 8-bit characters (ascii characters > 127).There's a comand line option for flex, -8, that makes it clean for 8
bit even if the system default is 7 bit.this command option is not available for the turbo pascal lex version.

Comment: "tenub"/ unicode range don't work too. i found this page but don't know how to implement the utf-8 in turbo pascal lex.http://www.w3.org/2005/03/23-lex-U

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you posted [**here**](http://www.w3.org/2005/03/23-lex-U)

The format you would use in Lex is:

```
(['\u00E1'-'\u00EC','\u00EE'-'\u00EF'] ['\u0080'-'\u00BF'] ['\u0080'-'\u00BF'])
```

It seems like you have to wrap the multibyte characters in single quotes `''`

---

### Relevant Links

Here's a page on [**Turbo Pascal LEX / FLEX and YACC / BISON** (translated from French to English)](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~manouvri/COMPILATION/LEXYACC.html&usg=ALkJrhifWX5WzxosSbHU3JUpe1yBk0B1Xg)

Answer (score 0):

after reading some docs and testing here is the working answer :

[-"'"a-zA-Z\200-\245]*

this regular expression use the octal value of accented characters starting from 200 to 245 in octal format.

by the way the Turbo pascal LEX don't support unicode characters.

best regards.